# How to stop OS X 10.11.6 (El Capitan) from using keychain

Tags: macos, password, keychain

I really despise the keychain "feature" in OS X. I do not want my computer or my browser to know my passwords.

**How do I stop keychain from being active completely?**

Everything I've looked at discusses how to change your password or make it more accessible, but I want to disable this altogether.

Answer (score 3):

You can remove all passwords stored in Keychain via menu File -> Delete Keychain "login". This will create a 'fresh' keychain; you only have to remember *not* to store any new passwords in it when the system asks for it.

[image]

---

For Safari, open its Preferences and go to the Passwords tab. Uncheck the 'AutoFill user names and passwords' option:

[image]